# extract numbers from string java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the numbers from the following string:

```
(1234-5869)|990-9797
```

I want all the numbers present in that string like

```
1234
5869
990
9797
```

Comment: If you say "I'm trying", you must have some code that does not work for you. Please add it to the question and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: `Integer[] result = Arrays.stream("1234-5869)|990-9797".split("\\D")).filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);`

Answer (score 0):

in your case you don't need any regex. You need to split your string.
look at this topic : [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

or if you want to make it without split you can replace all spetial caractere by a a blank space and then use a stringTokenizer like this :

```
String str = "(1234-5869)|990-9797";
str = str.replaceAll("\\D", " ")); // " 1234 5869  990 9797"

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

your answer will appear with the presentation you want

Answer (score -1):

- result==> String

  ```
  String string="(1234-5869)|990-9797";
  String onlyNumber= string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
  System.out.println("result==>"onlyNumber);
  ```
- result ==> array

  ```
  String string="(1234-5869)|990-9797";
  String normalizedString= string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ",");
  System.out.println(normalizedString);
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(normalizedString, ",");
  List<String> tabNumber= new ArrayList<String>();
  while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
      tabNumber.add((String) st.nextElement());
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Use replaceAll.

```
String str = "(1234-5869)|990-9797";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\D", " ")); // " 1234 5869  990 9797"
```

To get them into an array:

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\D");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [, 1234, 5869, , 990, 9797]
```

You can then make them into a string with a loop and a `StringBuilder` or something similar, and trim off any empty values.